# "Pointless button" won't change text

Tags: javascript, html, button

I'm trying to make a website with this pointless button on it

```
    <p id="pButt" style="position:absolute; top:500px; font-family:Impact, charcoal, sans-serif">Pointless button!</p>
<button type="button" onClick="pButt()" style="position:absolute; top:550px">Don't click it</button>

<script>
function pButt() {
 var textButt = textButt + 1;
 if (textButt === 1) {
 document.getElementById("pButt").innerHTML = "Seriously, it's pointless"
 }
 else {
  if (textButt === 2) {
  document.getElementById("pButt").innerHTML = "Ouch, that tickles!"
  else {
   if (textButt >= 3) {
   document.getElementById("pButt").innerHTML = "Ok, I'm bored of writing Javascript now. No point clicking anymore!"
}
}
}
}
</script>
```

I want it to change the text in the paragraph with id 'pButt' to 'Seriously, it's pointless' the first time, 'Ouch, that tickles!' second and 'Ok, I'm bored of writing Javascript now. No point clicking anymore!' third time. Why won't the code work? I'm pretty new to Javascript, but if there's some dumb spelling mistake I'm really sorry.

Comment: You have to declare and initialize `textButt` outside of `pButt`.

Comment: `var textButt = textButt + 1;` is pointless as `textButt` has not been defined yet :), `textButt` will now equal `NaN`

Comment: Also think about putting your messages in an array and then just use textButt as the index to the array, that way you wont have to write a lot of if statements

Comment: I thought "Pointless button" was some kind of a fancy term for new style of button in some fancy JS framework. Darn!

Comment: It's a good practice to avoid using inline styles... [Why Use CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Why_use_CSS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare and initialize `textButt` outside of `pButt`. The following will work:

```
<p id="pButt" style="position:absolute; top:500px; font-family:Impact, charcoal, sans-serif">Pointless button!</p>
<button type="button" onClick="pButt()" style="position:absolute; top:550px">Don't click it</button>

<script>
    var textButt = 0;
    function pButt() {
        textButt++;
        if (textButt === 1) {
            document.getElementById("pButt").innerHTML = "Seriously, it's pointless"
        } else if (textButt === 2) {
            document.getElementById("pButt").innerHTML = "Ouch, that tickles!"
        } else  if (textButt >= 3) {
            document.getElementById("pButt").innerHTML = "Ok, I'm bored of writing Javascript now. No point clicking anymore!"
        }
    }
</script>
```

Alternatively, you could slightly refactor:

```
<p id="pButt" style="position:absolute; top:500px; font-family:Impact, charcoal, sans-serif">Pointless button!</p>
<button type="button" onClick="pButt()" style="position:absolute; top:550px">Don't click it</button>

<script>
    var message, textButt = 0;
    function pButt() {
        switch(++textButt) {
            case 1:
                message = "Seriously, it's pointless";
                break;
            case 2:
                message = "Ouch, that tickles!";
                break;
            default:
                message = "Ok, I'm bored of writing Javascript now. No point clicking anymore!";
        }
        document.getElementById("pButt").innerHTML = message;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to move the `textButt` variable outside of the function. It's not persisted across button clicks now since it's a local variable. You should also initialize it to 0.

Answer (score 0):

you have to declare the `textButt` as a public variable

```
  var textButt = 0;
    function pButt() {
     textButt = textButt + 1;
     if (textButt === 1) {
     document.getElementById("pButt").innerHTML = "Seriously, it's pointless"
     }
     else {
      if (textButt === 2) {
      document.getElementById("pButt").innerHTML = "Ouch, that tickles!"
      else {
       if (textButt >= 3) {
       document.getElementById("pButt").innerHTML = "Ok, I'm bored of writing Javascript now. No point clicking anymore!"
    }
    }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from textButt being initialized inside the function, only increment should be within the function.
you can check 
  http://jsfiddle.net/D9HEU/

```
var textButt = 0;

 function pButt() {
     textButt++;
     if (textButt == 1) {
         document.getElementById("pButt").innerHTML = "Seriously, it's pointless"

     } else if (textButt == 2) {
         document.getElementById("pButt").innerHTML = "Ouch, that tickles!"
     } else if (textButt >= 3) {
         document.getElementById("pButt").innerHTML = "Ok, I'm bored of writing Javascript now. No point clicking anymore!"
     }

 }
```